# PhpStorm complains about adding key value to an array

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I have the following code:

```
            let self = this;
          
            for (const questionIndex in self.questions) {
                self.givenAnswers[questionIndex] = "";
            }
```

And PhpStorm is complaining about the line `self.givenAnswers[questionIndex] = "";` saying that I need to check if the object has the property.
The full message is:

> Possible iteration over unexpected (custom / inherited) members, probably missing hasOwnProperty check.

But the `givenAnswers` variable is an array and not an object, and I want to append new key and values. How do I remove the warning, or is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could add a `hasOwnProperty` check to fix the warning:

```
for (const questionIndex in self.questions) {
    if (self.questions.hasOwnProperty(questionIndex)) {
        self.givenAnswers[questionIndex] = "";
    }
}
```

If it's an array, I think iterating from 0 to its length would be less verbose:

```
for (let i = 0; i < self.questions.length; i++) {
    self.givenAnswers[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: Ok, the first one helped me to resolve the issue. It does seem kinda stupid for me on PHPStorm side - that if I am iterating over object keys - the object should have the key and why should it complain then. oO